# How to return error from `taskEither.tryCatch`

Tags: functional-programming, fp-ts

I have the following probem:

```
const something = taskEither.tryCatch(
  async()  => {
    const random = Math.random();
    if (random < 0.5) throw new Error();
    return random < 0.25;
  },
  () => 'innerError' as const,
);
taskEither.tryCatch(
  async() => {
    const result = await something();
    if (either.isLeft(result)) return result.left;
    if (!result.right) throw new Error();
    return result.right;
  },
  () => 'OuterError' as const,
)
```

The type I want is `TaskEither<'OuterError' | 'InnerError', true>` but I get `TaskEither<'OuterError', 'InnerError' | true>`.

How can I get the Error in the left side to the Error in the right side?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my problem. But I wonder if there is a more idiomatic way to handle this because `err` is typed as `unknown` and forces to manually annotate the type. This can be problematic when there are many different errors thrown by the inner function.

```
taskEither.tryCatch(
  async() => {
    const result = await something();
    if (either.isLeft(result)) throw(result.left);
    if (!result.right) throw new Error();
    return result.right;
  },
  (err) => {
    if (err === 'InnerError') return <'InnerError'>'InnerError';
    return 'OuterError' as const;
  }
)
```

Comment: It's correct that `err` is typed as `unknown` because in JS you can throw literally anything so the type of that error could be anything.